# Excel VLOOKUP - function #NAME

Tags: excel, reference, vlookup

could someone please tell me whats wrong with my =VLOOKUP(E3;E:E; 2;0) - function?
In German it is the following: =SVERWEIS(E3;E:E; 2;0)
I never used the VLOOKUP - function before so I just try to make it work somehow. Unfortunately it does not get the reference right, although I compare numbers with numbers in the same workbook. I also tried =SVERWEIS(E3;E:E; 2;1) but it didn't work either.
Thank's a lot!
Greetings!

Comment: Second argument is the complete range that holds the searched value and the one you want to retrieve, Because you specified to get second column, `E:E` is just 1 column. It should be `E:F` at least. Anyways, a data example, and expected output will help, indeed.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns is right however that wouldn't lead to the `#NAME` error

Comment: Thank you, please see my comment beneath :)

Comment: So you are searching a value that you already got? It makes no sense at all. Why you want to retrieve a value from column E:E searching that same value in column E:E? As I said, clearly you need to post a data example, expected output and explain what are you trying to do. IF you just want to check if a value **exists** in column E, use COUNTIF

Comment: Well actually the columns I want to search through (E:E) is in a different workbook. Unfortunately it is not working and therefore I tried to make the function working by just making references in one workbook for reduction of complexity. But somehow even this easy example is not working out. 'couse I must at least get some output, but I only receive an error, so I was wondering if my formula might be totally wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the number 2 for the column where the values are located, but your range is only 1 column.  If the value you want to return is in column E then the number 2 should be a 1.  But if the value you want to return is in column F, then you need to change the range to include column F

Comment: Thank you, I guess I chose a pretty bad example. Lets change it slightly: =VLOOKUP(A3;E:E; 2;0) Anyway, my expected number is in column E. Why should I change the range, if I am only interested in column E?

Comment: The lookup array can be a single column, but the number 2 is the column index.  If your lookup array is only 1 column, your column index cannot be greater than 1